# What is the most efficient way to select data from multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, firebird

In order to retrieve the data I want to display I need to access multiple tables in my database.

For example with **tables A,B,C,D**:

```
  A              B                  C              D 
Id|Date     Id|Size|Price       Size|Dep       Code|Des
 1|1.2.19    3|  XL|10.00          L|AA          AA|Altora
 2|2.3.19    4|   L|10.00         XL|CC          BB|Barb
 3|2.7.19    5| XXL|10.00          S|DD          CC|Culic
 4|3.9.19    6|  XL|5.00         XXL|DD          DD|Dold
 5|4.9.19    4|   S|12.00        XXL|DD          EE|Elle
```

I would like to **sum the B.price** for each **D.departement** between certain dates:

- A -> B with **Id**
- B -> C with **Size**
- C -> D with **Code**

For the moment I achieved what I wanted by writing multiple joins.

```
select D.code, D.des, sum(B.price) 
from A
  join B on A.id = B.id
  join C on B.size = C.size
  join D on C.dep = D.code
where A.date between 1.1.19 and 6.1.19
group by D.dep, D.des
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it and/or is my solution correct?

Comment: You don't actually need table `A` in your query.

Comment: I just edited my question in order to justify the use of the A table. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Also added a des colum to D in order to get this information in my select @gordon-linoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for a wrong join condition (`C.dep = D.dep` should be `C.dep = D.code`), your solution looks to be correct given the information you provided. It is harder to judge the efficiency, but it is probably efficient enough. I'm saying this, because Firebird's optimizer is not really that great, so sometimes changing the order of joins in your query may improve the performance of a query, where in other database systems the optimizer would do that for you.

Additionally, performance can depend on the presence or absence of indexes on the fields you're joining or using in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I will stick with my "multiple joins" solution. 
+ I edited the post to correct the `C.dep = D.code`

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You don't seem to need tables `A` or `D`:

```
select c.dep, sum(B.price) 
from B join
     C
     on B.size = C.size
group by c.dep;
```

It *is* possible that you do need the tables.  They may be needed for filtering or for multiplying the number of rows.  However, based on the `select` and sample data, they are not needed.

Comment: With the changes the OP made to their question, this answer is no longer correct.